# Why can the multiprocessing module pickle functions that call anonymous functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, python-multiprocessing

I was writing some code (running on a Mac) that depended on composing a long list of functions and applying the resulting function to a list using multiprocessing.  If I run the following code, I get an `AttributeError`, because the `multiprocessing` module needs to pickle the function and it can't pickle anonymous functions.

```
import multiprocessing
import functools

def compose(*functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions, lambda x: x

twox = lambda x: 2*x
funcs = [twox, twox, twox]
operation = compose(*funcs)
nums = range(10)

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
p.map(operation, nums) ## raises an AttributeError
```

I understand why this code fails.  What's puzzling is that if I instead create a function that just calls operation, everything works fine.  In other words, the following code returns the correct result:

```
def wrapped_operation(x):
    return operation(x)

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
p.map(wrapped_operation, nums) ## returns [0,8,16,...]
```

Why is this?  It seems to me that if Python needs to pickle wrapped_operation, it should run into the sub-problem of pickling operation and throw some kind of error.  Is there something I'm misunderstanding here?  And is there any problem with just wrapping the anonymous function with a non-anonymous one?

Comment: It's actually a `pickle` limitation, not `multiprocessing`'s.

Comment: Right, I know pickle doesn't work on anonymous functions (apologies if that wasn't clear), but I can't understand why it can pickle functions that *call* anonymous functions.

Comment: Are you on linux/mac? It should fail on Windows also because the process state can't be pickled. On a forking system, children get a copy-on-write view of memory. `pickle` only sends function names to the other side, expecting the receiver to `import` the module to get the code object (and because of fork , it doesn't have to import). That function has view of the parent memory space so sees functions in the global variable.

Comment: I'm running this on a Mac

Comment: For running on Windows, as well as Unixes, you  need to add an `if __name__ == `__main__': before the `p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)` line and indent that and all the following lines one level.

Comment: In your first snippet, `funcs` **is** undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapped_operation` is a normal named function. The call to it can be pickled from parent to child process.

In your second variant creation and calling of the anonymous `operation` happens solely in the child process (or it happened in parent which was forked earlier, depending on `multiprocessing` operation mode). So it never crossed the border between processes.